# android - Cammera permissions - Google Play?

Tags: android, permissions, android-camera

In my app I use this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

When i start the app, I check the `flashlight support`. When the Device supports `Flashlight` then i show the layout "`Flashlight`", otherwise I show the layout "`No_Flashlight`".

Everything works great.

Now my problem is `Google Play`. I have to smartphones. One with Flashlight and one with no flashlight. When i go to Google Play with my flashlight smartphone i see my app.

But when i go to Google play with my no flashlight smartphone i don't see the app.

Comment: Does your other phone have a Camera?

Comment: Yes. One with camera and flashlight and one with no camera and no flashlight.

Comment: @Shrikant has given the correct answer. You need to distinguish between what hardware functions your application mandatorily requires and ones which are not mandatory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
              android:required="false" />
```

The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it.

Because Google Play filters the applications that are visible to users, so that users can see and download only those applications that are compatible with their devices. One of the ways it filters applications is by feature compatibility.

For detailed explanation, please see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html